# VS does not recognize the terminal shell path on Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, terminal

I am trying to use remote SSH extension of Visual studio code, but there are a problem during connection:
**The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" does not exist.**

Yes, this path doesn't exist on my PC, and I go to correcting it by modifier settings.json file.

Like this: **"terminal.integrated.automationShell.windows": "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe"**

But the Visual code still doesn't recognize this new path and throw above error! What's wrong here? Anyone can help me please, thanks in advance!